# python beautifulsoup scraping archive pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I know there's a datetime issue - not sure where. When I try to scrape the progrssively older tables my returned data is a loop through today's data. I think I need another encapsulating loop to get through to the older pages

How shouold I address the issue?

```
from urlparse import urljoin
from urllib2 import urlopen
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

url = "http://www.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3022-mfsctrscan-moneyflow-{}.html?mod=mdc_pastcalendar"
start = datetime.today()

def only_weekdays_range(start, n):
    i = 0
    wk_days = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
    while i != n:
        while start.weekday() not in wk_days:
            start -= timedelta(days=1)
        yield start
    i += 1
    start -= timedelta(days=1)


for _ in (only_weekdays_range(start, 5)):
    print ("data for {}".format(start.strftime("%b %d %y")))
    url = url.format(start.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
    print 'Retrieving information from: ' + url
    print '\n'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    div_main = soup.find('div', {'id': 'column0'})
    table_one = div_main.find('table')
    def target_row(tag):
       is_row = len(tag.find_all('td')) > 5
       row_name = tag.name == 'tr'
       return is_row and row_name

    rows = table_one.find_all(target_row)[1:]
#print rows
    for row in rows:
        cells = row.findAll('td')
        industry = cells[0].get_text()
        data = {
           'name' : cells[0].get_text()
        print data
        print '\n'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two variables `start`

- global `start = datetime.today()`
- local `def only_weekdays_range(start, n):`

You change local `start` in function

```
 start -= timedelta(days=1)
```

and you return it using `yield` and then you assign it to `_` in `for _ in ...` but you doesn't use it. You use global one which is not changed.

You have to use value from `_` (ie. as `new_date`)

```
for new_date in (only_weekdays_range(start, 5)):
    print ("data for {}".format(new_date.strftime("%b %d %y")))
    url = url.format(new_date.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
    print 'Retrieving information from: ' + url
```

But you have wrong indentions in function

```
def only_weekdays_range(start, n):
    i = 0
    wk_days = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
    while i != n:
        while start.weekday() not in wk_days:
            start -= timedelta(days=1)
        yield start
        i += 1
        start -= timedelta(days=1)
```

---

Working example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# --- functions ---

def only_weekdays_range(start, n):
    one_day = timedelta(days=1)
    for _ in range(n):
        while start.weekday() > 4:
            start -= one_day
        yield start
        start -= one_day

# --- main ---

start = datetime.today()

for new_date in only_weekdays_range(start, 10):
    print ("data for {}".format(new_date.strftime("%b %d %y %a")))
```

Result:

```
data for Feb 03 17 Fri
data for Feb 02 17 Thu
data for Feb 01 17 Wed
data for Jan 31 17 Tue
data for Jan 30 17 Mon
data for Jan 27 17 Fri
data for Jan 26 17 Thu
data for Jan 25 17 Wed
data for Jan 24 17 Tue
data for Jan 23 17 Mon
```

---

**EDIT:** with `if` instead of `while`

```
def only_weekdays_range(start, n):
    one_day = timedelta(days=1)
    for _ in range(n):
        weekday = start.weekday()
        if weekday > 4:
            start -= one_day * (weekday-4)
        yield start
        start -= one_day
```

---

**EDIT:** I see other problem

In

```
 url = url.format(...)
```

you overwrite `url` so in next loop you can't change it.

Use

```
full_url = url.format(...)

r = requests.get(full_url)
```

Comment: So the text for "retreiving info. from"  is changing - but the URL is not incrementing to reflect the returns from the older dates - constantly pushing data from today - saying it's from older dates

Comment: the same problem - you have to use `new_date` instead `start` - it is obvious. BTW: see first code - there is  `new_date` in `url.format(new_date.strftime('%Y%m%d'))`

Comment: Now I see other problem `url = url.format(...)` - you overwrite `url` so in next loop you can't change date - use `full_url = url.format(...)`